# Can't connect to a local database using Monetdb.R

Tags: r, monetdb

I'm trying to set a local connection to a database using Monetdb.R, but for some reason it is not working. I'm using the latest version of monetdb (MonetDB5 64 bits "Jan2014-SP3", 2014-07-25 release) in a Windows 7.

Here it is a short reproducible example:

```
> library(MonetDB.R)
Carregando pacotes exigidos: DBI
Carregando pacotes exigidos: digest
> conn <- dbConnect(dbDriver("MonetDB"), "monetdb://localhost/demo")
Error in .mapiRead(con) : ERROR reading MAPI block header (0)
```

I haven't seen this error occuring with other users...

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252        LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] MonetDB.R_0.9.4 digest_0.6.4    DBI_0.3.0      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

Comment: All the examples in the help pages use `conn <- dbConnect(MonetDB.R(), "monetdb://localhost/demo")` rather than `conn <- dbConnect(dbDriver("MonetDB"), "monetdb://localhost/demo")`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I have... and that didn't work either. Thanks for the suggestion, @MrFlick !

Comment: Are other users using Windows too?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question, @Pascal. There are no other users... I'm trying to use R as a client to connect to a local database stored in my HDD. So... everything is stored in the same Windows 7 environment. Code above is an exemple taken from the help files of MonetDB.R.

Comment: @RogerioJB I cite what you wrote "I haven't seen this error occurring with other users...".

Comment: Oh, sorry! I mean I haven't seen a similar question/error notification. So I suppose there are not many users who experienced such an error...

Comment: I know SO mods hate it when people suggest outside resources but why haven't you contacted the maintainer?

Comment: @BondedDust, I haven't because they recommend us to make our questions here first. So... I decided to try it (it's my first question on SO)

Comment: This is the right place to ask such questions by the way. We suggest SO for this.

Comment: hi, `MonetDBLite` (on CRAN) now replaces `MonetDB.R` and runs embedded (like `RSQLite`).  for more detail, see https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Is it as fast as the regular version, @Anthony?

Comment: @RogerioJB data transfers between R and MonetDB are now much faster and within-MonetDB-only commands are exactly the same speed

Comment: By the way, nice post at your webpage, @Anthony. I thought it would be nice to share the address here for whoever may be interested in this topic:
http://www.asdfree.com/2016/06/monetdblite-because-fast.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MonetDB.R 0.9.5 has been released to CRAN. Windows binary distributions should be available shortly.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!
(Sorry... I do not have reputation enough to evaluate your answer)

Comment: in order for MonetDB.R v 0.9.4 to work, you might need to manually install an older version of the DBI package -- http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DBI/DBI_0.2-7.tar.gz