# R > Monetdb, dbConnect error (package Monetdb.R)

Tags: r, monetdb

I'm getting an error when trying to connect (dbConnect()) from within R to MonetDB (using MonetDB.R). There is a ([related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25882427/cant-connect-to-a-local-database-using-monetdb-r)) and I also tryed the sugestions there ( (a) use MonetDB.R beta version 0.9.5 or (a) use the regular MonetDB.R but replace DBI package with an earlier version (0.2-7)) without success.

This is the code and errors:

```
library(MonetDB.R)
options( "monetdb.sequential" = TRUE )
setwd("C:/Users/lucas_000/Desktop/Curso R/importa_RAIS")
batfile <-
  monetdb.server.setup(
    database.directory = paste( getwd() , "/MonetDB", sep="") ,
    monetdb.program.path = 
      ifelse(.Platform$OS.type == "windows" , "C:/Program Files/MonetDB/MonetDB5" , "" ) ,
    dbname = "RAIS" , dbport = 50003
  )

batfile <- "C:/Users/lucas_000/Desktop/Curso R/importa_RAIS/MonetDB/RAIS.bat"
dbname <- "RAIS"
dbport <- 50003  
pid <- as.numeric(monetdb.server.start( batfile ))
# output indicates:  MonetDB 5 server v11.17.21 "Jan2014-SP3"

db <- dbConnect( MonetDB.R() , "monetdb://localhost:5003/RAIS" , wait = TRUE )

Assertion Failed!
Program: C\:Program Files\RStudio\bin\x64\rsession.exe
File: mapi.c, Line 91
Expression: IS_INTEGER(port)
#Then RStudio displays an error: "R Session Aborted"
```

Sistem details: 
Windows 8.0, on RStudio, Version 0.98.1062

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

other attached packages:
 [1] R.utils_1.33.0     R.oo_1.18.0        R.methodsS3_1.6.1  downloader_0.3    
 [5] RCurl_1.95-4.3     bitops_1.0-6       sqlsurvey_0.6-11   survey_3.30-3     
 [9] KernSmooth_2.23-12 MonetDB.R_0.9.4    digest_0.6.4       DBI_0.3.1         

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.1
```

Attempted solutions and respective errors:

a) TRYING TO INSTALL MonetDB.R_0.9.5.zip (beta version)

```
library(devtools)
remove.packages("MonetDB.R")
install_url("http://homepages.cwi.nl/~hannes/R/MonetDB.R_0.9.5.zip")

* installing *binary* package 'MonetDB.R' ...
cp: unknown option -- )
Try `/usr/bin/cp --help' for more information.
Aviso: execução do comando 'cp -R . "C:/Users/lucas_000/Documents/R/win-        library/3.1/MonetDB.R" || ( tar cd - .| (cd "C:/Users/lucas_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/MonetDB.R" && tar -xf -))' teve status 1
ERROR: installing binary package failed
* removing 'C:/Users/lucas_000/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/MonetDB.R'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

b) Keeping the MonetDB.R regular version (cran) but changing the DBI to an earlier version (also sugested on SO):

```
remove.packages("DBI")
library(devtools)
install_url("cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/DBI/DBI_0.2-7.tar.gz")
library(DBI)
db <- dbConnect( MonetDB.R() , "monetdb://localhost:5003/RAIS" , wait = TRUE )
```

# gives same error as above, 
    Assertion Failed!
    Program: C:Program Files\RStudio\bin\x64\rsession.exe
    File: mapi.c, Line 91
    Expression: IS_INTEGER(port)
    #Then RStudio displays an error: "R Session Aborted"

Comment: the beta version is a binary package, could you try installing that via the "install package from zip file" route?

Comment: hi, `MonetDBLite` (on CRAN) now replaces `MonetDB.R` and runs embedded (like `RSQLite`).  for more detail, see https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/MonetDBLite/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MonetDB.R` 0.9.5 has been released to CRAN. Windows binary distributions should be available shortly.

Answer (score 1):

The error may have been in the line where you create the dbConnect.

Your code (incorrect port):

```
db <- dbConnect( MonetDB.R() , "monetdb://localhost:5003/RAIS" , wait = TRUE )
```

Correct code:

```
db <- dbConnect( MonetDB.R() , "monetdb://localhost:50003/RAIS" , wait = TRUE )
```

Another issue with this code may have been choosing dbport to be be 50 003; I believe the default is 50 000.